# How to login to Youtube using curl?

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube

How could I login to Youtube using curl?
I found some articles here, but none of the code's seem to be working anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you're using curl instead of the published API? http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html  Google's TOS do not allow screen scraping.

Comment: Where do you see Googles TOS not allowing screen scraping? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't login to YouTube using cURL but you *can* accomplish the same thing by using [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OAuth_Authentication).

Comment: Er, all the POST parameters for OAuth are displayed in full and in complete detail on the page I linked to in my answer.